# How can I get audio from videos on youtube like "video to mp3" in android?

Tags: android

I am making an app in which I need to convert youtube video files to audio in android, is there any library or method, with which I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If your application do such things Playstore will not accept your application,because it vialots google policies and youtube will not give access for you  but if you want normal videos use ffmpeg library.